# how to show latest data in core plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I'm using core plot to draw scattered plot. I have ten data, such as (1,45),(2,54),(3,35),(4,44),...,(9,43),(10,50). The window can show 5 data. If I scroll left, then the window can show other data.

Now the problem is, it always show the first 5 data at first. If I want to show the last 5 data first , how can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot space controls what data is visible in the plot area. To display points with x-values between 5 and 10, set the `xRange` to a range with `location` 5 and `length` 5.